# Linker Error in C, Xcode. Linking object files (.o) fails. Not sure how to include makefile in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, macos, makefile, linker-errors

I have created Xcode project and added C files and headers that I want to use. However, I can't figure out how to link object files and that's why I get Linker Error.

[image: tree of my files and linking error]

Speller.c has main method. And now I am trying to link dict-tree.o and speller.o from header file dict.h .

I can do it from terminal using makefile that I wrote, but I need a proper debugging and that is why decided to use Xcode.

Is there a way to include makefile, and compile program through that makefile on Xcode?

Makefile content:

```
  CFLAGS=-g -Wall -std=c99
  CC=gcc

  # "make tree" or "make hash" to compile

  tree: speller.o dict-tree.o
       $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

  hash: speller.o dict-hash.o
       $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: This looks like it is because you need to add separate project folders (re-adding the same speller.c into both of them) for each separate executable in the main Xcode project file... since it will try to link BOTH dict-tree.o and dict-hash.o into the same executable the way you set it up, which is different from the makefile, you are getting duplicate symbol errors.

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more precise? Do you mean that I have 2 files that could be linked(in this case dict-hash.o and dict-tree.o)? If this is what you mean, that is exactly what I am trying to solve. I don't know how to tell Xcode to chose the one I want. Basically, I am not sure how to use makefile, described above in the Xcode  P.S was written to someone who deleted his comment

Comment: Try right clicking on the Spellchecker Target, and then "duplicate" - naming one target SpellHash and renaming the other SpellTree or something like that.  Then, delete dict-hash.[c,h] from the Tree target, and delete dict-tree.[c,h] from the Hash target, and then build each target separately.

Comment: @JohnH I did try to remove dict-hash.c file from the folder before. However, it was producing similar error.

Comment: try simply running from a terminal command line in your source directory `gcc -Wall -std=c99 speller.c dict-tree.c -o tree` and see if you are warning free and get a vaild executable.  If not, you have other issues with your code.

Comment: Compiling from a terminal works fine. The makefile that I included above works, the thing is I am not sure how to do it in Xcode

Comment: @JohnH it did compile after completely deleting it. I have just restarted Xcode and it worked which is strange, but happens quite often.

Answer (score 1):

After having this same problem, finding this question and then some further poking around, I discovered you need to declare the C-based functions in your C++ file as such:

```
extern "C" void function_from_c_file(int var, int var);
```

This has to take the place of the standard function declaration in the header file associated with the C file.

Basically you need a separate header file for use in your C++ files, or hand code them into your C++ files as needed.

I found help in these two links:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2197357?tstart=0
(go down to the post by "etresoft")

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#call-c

Good luck!